# about php safe_write timeout

Tags: php, timeout, cgi, suspend

all
    My error case is a normal web download service, and web server is lighttpd, and use php-fpm to process download request like this:

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

But after running one day, almost all php cgi are suspended in fwrite function. I use gdb to debug it, and find they were suspended in safe_write function in fastcgi.c.
  I want to know how can I set time out for this case? I have tried stream_set_timeout, ini_set('default_socket_timeout'), and they did not work.